# Can I work remotely from Singapore for a UK company?

Tags: taxes, working, singapore

My spouse is being posted from her job in the UK to Singapore.  It will be under a local contract.  I’m accompanying as the spouse on a Dependant’s Pass (DP)

I currently work as a remote working contractor for a UK company.  I’m not paid directly by them but through an agency.  Both have no issues with me working abroad since the location of my desk doesn’t matter to them.  So basically I’d be based in Singapore working for a UK company whilst being paid and taxed in the UK without any connection to a Singaporean company.

My research hasn’t found any issues so far under Singaporean regulations that would either prevent this or incur Singaporean taxes.  Does anyone have experience of this?

Comment: [About tax residency status](https://dollarsandsense.sg/business/working-from-anywhere-things-you-need-to-know-before-working-remotely-overseas/)

Comment: [This Travel.SE question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177187/visiting-singapore-company-office-short-tem-to-work-which-visa) is not a duplicate, and doesn't address taxes. But it does address the legality of working remotely while in Singapore. You may find it useful.

Comment: "My research hasn’t found any issues so far under Singaporean regulations that would either prevent this or incur Singaporean taxes." See https://www.iras.gov.sg/taxes/individual-income-tax/employees/scenario-based-faqs-for-working-in-singapore-and-abroad/i-am-working-for-a-foreign-employer "You will be taxed on income earned for the period you render services in Singapore even if your income is not received in Singapore."

Answer (score 1):

Well, my spouse contacted the MOM and been advised there’s no issue in Singapore about this.

I’ll be paying my employment taxes in the UK whilst working for a UK company.